# Debug recursive thread call in C

Tags: c, multithreading, directory

I have been trying to debug my code whenever I had free-time for the past day and a half and I don't know what is wrong with my code. When I add the `close()` function to a recursive call, the program gives me an invalid pointer. But when I remove the `close()` function call the program runs fine, except it does not do what it is supposed to do, which is:

- add up all the file sizes in a user
  input directory
- open sub-directories, if any, and add
  up all the files inside the
  sub-directory

Instead, it adds up all the file sizes in the input directory and is able to open the last sub-directory and add the files within that directory to the total file size count.

I am trying to do this with threads. The `main()` function creates one main thread from the user input directory and runs `opendirectory()` off the bat.

```
/*
 * Iterates through given directory
 */
void *opendirectory(void *t)
{
 pthread_mutex_lock(&dirlock);
 DIR *dpntr;
 struct dirent *dentry;
 char new_directory[512], dir = t;

 printf("OPENING DIRECTORY ... %s\n", t);

 /* Checks if given directory can be opened */
 if((dpntr = opendir(t)) == NULL) {
  printf("DIRECTORY FAILED ...%s\n",t);
  perror("ERROR -- COULD NOT OPEN DIR");
  pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 printf("DIRECTORY OPENED: %s\n", t);

 /* Read each file in current directory */
 while ((dentry = readdir(dpntr)) != NULL ) {
  /* Ignore special directories */
  if(strcmp(dentry -> d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dentry -> d_name, "..") == 0) {
   continue;
  } else {
   compilelist( t, dentry->d_name );
  }
 }

 pthread_mutex_unlock(&dirlock);
 /* Checks if directory can be closed */
 if(closedir(dpntr) < 0)
  printf("ERROR CLOSING %s.\n", t);

}
```

This is the function that will determine if a new thread should be created and is supposed to run recursively.

```
/*
 * Determines if current file is a directory
 * Creates a new thread if true
 */
void compilelist (const char* dirname, const char *filename)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&filelock);
    struct stat statdata;
    char *filepathname, *dpntr;

    /* Allocate memory for filepathname */
    if((filepathname = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(dirname))) == NULL)
    {
        printf("CANNOT ALLOCATE MEMORY FOR FILE PATH NAME.");
        pthread_exit(NULL);
    }

    /* Concats directory name with file name */
    if(dirname[strlen(dirname) -1] == '/')
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pathlock);
        sprintf(filepathname, "%s%s", dirname, filename);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pathlock);
    }else
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pathlock);
        sprintf(filepathname, "%s/%s", dirname, filename);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pathlock);
    }

    lstat(filepathname, &statdata);

    /* Calls print_statdata() if current item is a file */
    if(!(S_ISDIR(statdata.st_mode)))
    {
        printf("FILE: %s\n", filepathname);
        if(!stat( filepathname, &statdata))
        {
            print_statdata( filename, &statdata );
        }
        else {
            fprintf (stderr, "GETTING STAT FOR %s", filepathname);
            perror( "ERROR IN STATDATA WHILE GETTING STAT");
        }
    }
    /* Recursive call to opendirectory() */
    else {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&dircountlock);
        dirCount++;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&dircountlock);
        dpntr = filepathname;
        free(filepathname);
        printf("SUB-DIRECTORY THREAD: %s\nTHREAD ID NUMBER: %d\n", dpntr, dirCount);
        pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
        pthread_create(&threads[dirCount-1], &attr, opendirectory, (void *)dpntr);
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&filelock);

}
```

Here is the `main()`

```
/*
 * Main function prompts user for a directory
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    char *dPtr;
    // pthread_attr_t attr;

    printf("ENTER A DIRECTORY:\n\t");
    scanf("%s", directory);
    dPtr = directory;

    /* Initialize mutex and condition variable objects */
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&filelock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&dirlock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_init(&dircountlock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init (&count_threshold_cv, NULL);

    /* For portability, explicitly create threads in a joinable state */
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
    pthread_create(&threads[0], &attr, opendirectory, (void *)dPtr);

    /* Wait for all threads to complete */
    for (i = 0; i < dirCount; i++) {
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
    }

    printf("TOTAL DIRECTORY SIZE: %d\n", dirSize);

    /* Clean up and exit */
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&filelock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&dirlock);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&dircountlock);
    pthread_cond_destroy(&count_threshold_cv);
    pthread_exit (NULL);

}
```

And the global variables ...

```
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_mutex_t dirlock;
pthread_mutex_t filelock;
pthread_mutex_t dircountlock;
pthread_mutex_t threadlock;
pthread_cond_t count_threshold_cv;
pthread_attr_t attr;
pthread_t threads[128]; // handles up to 128 threads (i.e. 128 directories, change accordingly)
char directory[512];
int dirSize = 0;
int dirCount = 1; // user's input directory
```

I feel that the `pthread_create()` called at the bottom of the `compilelist()` function is not working properly. The threads[] refers to a global array of threads that has a default size of 20, assuming that there will be no more than 20 total directories. dirCount starts off at 1 because of the user's input directory and increases as new directories are encountered.

Comment: If you ever want to get help with this, you'll have to provide the entire source (where's dPtr declared? dir = t is wrong, etc...)

Comment: Can you post the code to main() ? Or at least where you are setting up thread attributes / handling joining / etc ?

Comment: I will edit my post in a bit, but at the time when I was thinking of a way to make it recursive, I made most of my variables global ... Might be a very newbie mistake, but any pointers would be great! I am in the process of changing some pointers from global to local.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found 2 problems of your code:

1. As wrang-wrang metioned, closedir(t) leads segfault.
2. "char filepathname[512];" of compilelist() is a local memory buffer, but you pass it to your thread (opendirectory) and use it continuously. You should use copying or dynamic-allocation instead.

Effo Upd@2009nov17: 
After fixing above 2 points, it works fine on my FC9 x86_64 so far. Btw: threads number 20 is really not enough.

Comment: Will edit post right now for closedir(), forgot to update that in last edit. I will definitely check the char filepathname[512] usage and consider how to go about it. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, so I believe I have set it up correctly to use dynamic allocation instead, but I am still getting errors on threads not opening up sub-directories. I will post my new code in a bit.

Comment: Am I not supposed to free(filepathname)? I thought I had to do so in order to malloc correctly for recursive calls ...

Comment: 1. free it in the thread opendirectory(). 2. if point 1 then do dynamic-alloc in main too. 3. don't forget to free it on other branches such as !ISDIR() and opendir() failure, and so on.

Comment: Hrm ... Maybe it's just me, but it seems to work when I don't free(filepathname) and it works fine on smaller directories in my situation ... Thanks for your help!

Comment: Okay, I just saw your new comment ... Will give that a shot too!

Comment: ok. another reminder - w/ you new code "filepathname = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(dirname)" the length allocated is not enough.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

```
dpntr = opendir(t)
```

...

```
if(closedir(t) < 0)
```

should be:

```
if(closedir(dpntr) < 0)
```

Comment: OH ... thanks ... that was a simple mistake that I seriously overlooked, should have triple checked that!

Comment: I have changed it, but I am still getting a segmentation fault when I run the program on my laptop. Can't seem to connect to a Linux system by ssh'ing at the moment to test ...

Answer (score 0):

First problem:

> whenever I had free-time for the past day and a half

Don't do that, your brain isn't built for it. Allocate a time, tell your workmates/wife-and-kids that, if they bother you during this time, there will be gunshots and police involvement :-)

Other problems: no idea (hence the community wiki).

Comment: One thing to watch out for, @Kenji (I don't think this is your *specific* problem). I can't see, with a cursory glance, anything that prevents the main thread from changing filepathname before your child thread has a chance to use it (via the dPtr pointer).

Comment: I think you may be on to something, I am trying to switch some global variables to local and going to recompile ...

Comment: @Kenji, what I tend to do in that case is have a mutex-protected flag variable. Main thread sets it to 1 before creating child thread then loops until it's 0. Child thread copies relevant data (data, not pointers to data) to local storage then sets it to 0 and carries on. That guarantees each thread is not stepping on the other.